# How can I make a form displayed only under its parent?

Tags: javascript, php, html, parent-child

I'm creating a comment-reply function where I would like the reply-form to show up under its parent when users presses the "Reply"-button.

Right now my code makes the form show up under every comment and not only the specific "parent-comment-reply-button". How can I avoid the form on other comments?

My code looks like this:

**HTML**

```
    <head>
        <?php
        include ('headCont.php');?>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
        include('navBar.php');?>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="box">
                     <div>
                        <!------------container------->
                        <form action="" method ="POST">
                            Namn: <br>
                            <input type="text" name ="name"><br>
                            Kommentar: <br>
                            <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Ställ en fråga" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea><br>
                            <input type ="submit" name ="submit" value="Skicka"> 
                        </form><br>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <?php 

                        include ('commentBox/storeComments.php');
                        include ('commentBox/getComments.php');?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->

        <footer>
            <?php
            include ('footer.php');
            ?>
        </footer>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="jsOld/jquery.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#show").click(function(){
            $(".reply-form").show();
        });
        $("#hide").click(function(){
            $(".reply-form").hide();
        });
    });

</script>
```

**getComments**

```
    <?php
include ('connectDB.php');
if($connect){
    mysqli_select_db($connect, "comments");
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY `id` DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query2);

    $comments = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $name = $row['name'];
        $comment = $row['comment'];
        $date = $row['date'];

        echo "
                    <div style='width:60%' class='col-lg-12'>
                        <div class='panel panel-default'>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>
                                <strong> $name </strong><span style='float:right'class='text-muted'>$date</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class='panel-body'>$comment
                                <button id='show' style='float:right'>Reply</button>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /panel panel-default -->
                    </div><!-- /col-sm-5 -->";

        echo "      <div class='col-lg-12 padd'>
                    <form method='POST' action='' class='reply-form'>
                        Namn:<br>
                            <input name='_method' type='text'</input><br>
                            Kommentar:<br>
                            <textarea name='reply_comment' cols='50' rows='10'></textarea>
                            <div class='button-group'>
                                <input type='submit' name='submit_reply' value='Skicka'></input>
                                <button id='hide' type='submit' name='close' value='Stäng'>Stäng</input>
                            </div>
                    </form>  
                </div>";
    }
}
?>
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the form inside the parent DOM. Which means, the following like should be at the end of the your send echo statement. And the `.reply-form` should be hidden initially using css.

```
</div><!-- /col-sm-5 -->";
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML IDs show and hide can appear multiple times in your DOM, keep in mind that HTML ids should be unique. So it would be best to change it to classes.

Now to the answer your question you could try to add a counter, this basically connects the form to the show button, example:

```
 <button id='show' style='float:right' data-counter="0">Reply</button>

 <form method='POST' action='' class='reply-form reply-form-0'>

$("#show").click(function(){
        var counter = $(this).data("counter");
        $(".reply-form-"+counter).show();
    });
```